# Vignette does not generate the result of a function as writing a R package

Tags: r, r-markdown, vignette

I have an external dataset in /data folder as I am developing a R package.  I call it data_m. `devtools::check()` shows now errors of the dataset.

As I run the vignette with Knit, however, I could not see the results of any functions, such as `colnames(data_m)` or the functions that I wrote.

For instance

```` ```r
colnames(data_m)
``` ````

only gives me the code `colnames(data_m)` instead of the column names of the dataset.

Also,

```` ```{r}
colnames(data_m)
``` ````

generates the error
`Error in this data.frame(x): object`data_m`not found Calls: <Anonymous> ...withVisible -> eval -> eval -> colnames -> is.data.frame Execution halted`

As I run

`devtools::check()`

I also shows

`frequencyrank: no visible binding for global variable ‘data_m’`

I think there is a disconnection between the dataset and the vignette. But I am not sure what it is.

Could anyone let me know what the problem actually is? Thank you very much.

Comment: Could section *Embed code with knitr syntax* in RMarkdown cheat sheet help? https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/rmarkdown-cheatsheet-2.0.pdf

Comment: Restart your R session, then run the code section by section on the command line. See if you get the same error. Presumably `data_m` is missing.

Comment: Thank you. I think the most important problem would be the dataset is not visually binding in a global environment. I am seeking solution to this.